# Is there a way to verify whether the packets are received at a switch?

Tags: networking, routes, network-programming, switch-statement, router

I have a router1-switch-router2 connection. My problem is if I send a packet from router1 to router2, it is not received at router2. I am sure the ipaddress/subnet address are correct. And am also sure that packets are going out the router1. And I am also sure of the internal port connections of the switch. I have access to the onpath switch. Is there any specific command that can be used in the switch to check whether the packet is received or not? ARP itself not getting resolved

Comment: could you share some piece of code on sender and receiver side ?

Comment: At least as-is, this seems to really be a question about network configuration, not programming...

Comment: I connected the router1 with other router3(not router2) directly and it worked. In this problem the arp itself is not getting resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a packet capture app running on both the sender and receiver that would tell the incoming and outgoing packets on both boxes.

In this case probably your packet is getting dropped either on the sender or receiver side. There can be million reasons for a packet drop.  But this is a good step to start with.